# How to convert html output of JavaDocs to responsive web app

Tags: javascript, java, html, javadoc, maximo

I have the html output of some JavaDocs a software vendor provides for their Java  packages. The vendor doesn’t provide access to the source code, just the html files generated from the JavaDocs for those packages. Is it feasible to convert the html output to another format ideally so that the content can be consumed as a responsive web app rather than generic web pages that don’t work well with mobile devices and look very Web 1.0. Ideally I’m looking for software that’s already available to perform this task presuming there are many people with JavaDocs generated content that wish it was in a more readable format. TIA.

Comment: "_I’m looking for software that’s already available_" - The question may be closed because of this. See numbered bullet point 4 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): they "tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". But you can "describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I respectfully disagree @andrewjames. If I was asking for example, which is the best IDE to use for Python then there are numerous possible answers and those answers would be very subjective based on each responders personal requirements. I am asking for a way, any way, to take the html content produced by Oracle’s JavaDoc format and process it to represent it in a more human readable format, enable better indexing and searching of the content and ideally present it in a responsive manner (html output from JavaDoc does not read well on mobile devices and tablets)…

Comment: I have tried tools such as Dash for macOS https://kapeli.com/dash but this is largely just an application wrapper for the JavaDoc format to search and display the existing html files. I have searched for ways to process the html output to produce something like markdown or similar but have not found a process that works. I would think this is very much on-topic for SO given that the JavaDoc format is so common in Java and other coding.